# How to copy and paste content (Shapes and Links) in tab to other tab in JAVAFX?

Tags: javafx, nodes, clone, copy-paste

I am working on project in which I have to add nodes at certain location. I have multiple tabs created dynamically.I want to copy shapes from one tab and paste in another tab. [image]

I used this sample code but it takes snapshot. I want to copy shape like "group copy" by selecting all shape then paste in other tab. When I paste the shape it should work like shape FTA_0. `SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
params.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

WritableImage image = firstCanvas.snapshot(params, null);
secondCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D().drawImage(image, 0, 0);`

Comment: I am facing same problem.

Comment: Hi Alee let me know if you got some solution.

Comment: Post [mre] please (not the whole application but an **M** version : two tabs, one node to copy, to show the problem.